# Can Eclipse generate a default proguard configuration file

Tags: android, proguard

I'm trying to enable proguard code obfuscation on my Android project.  I see lots of questions over the years, but many of the threads are quite old and it's hard to tell how relevant they are for me.

I was unable to get Eclipse to generate a default proguard configuration file so I've been trying to piece one together and it's painful (The build I get from it crashes almost immediately and appears that it's obscuring some elements of the 3rd party libs I used in the app).  I can appreciate that a generated file might now be perfect, but it seems like it could at least take a crack at handling the project libs properly.

Here's the steps I've taken to try to enable proguard.

1  Make sure my Eclipse and Android SDKs where fully up to date.

2  edit project.properties, uncomment

> proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

3  Immediately build fails due to pro guard-project.txt not existing.  (here's where I wish it would generate one)

4  I created my own pro guard.config file at proguard-project.txt (contents shown below)

> -injars      bin/classes
>   -outjars     bin/classes-processed.jar
>   -libraryjars libs/FlurryAgent.jar:libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-4.1.1.jar
>   -libraryjars libs/commons-codec-1.4.jar
>   -libraryjars libs/commons-io-2.1.jar
>   -libraryjars libs/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
>   -libraryjars libs/httpclient-4.1.2.jar
>   -libraryjars libs/httpclient-cache-4.1.2.jar
>   -libraryjars libs/httpcore-4.1.3.jar
>   -libraryjars libs/httpmime-4.1.2.jar
>   -libraryjars libs/mapquest-android-sdk-1.0.3.jar
>   -libraryjars libs/oranjestad-notifications-1.0.jar
>
> -dontwarn org.apache.**
>   -dontwarn org.ietf.*
>
> -keepnames org.apache.**
>
> -dontpreverify
>   -repackageclasses ''
>   -allowaccessmodification
>   -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
>   -keepattributes *Annotation*
>
> -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
>   -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
>   -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
>   -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
>
> -keep public class * extends android.view.View {
>       public (android.content.Context);
>       public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
>       public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
>       public void set*(...); }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
>       public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet); }
>
> -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
>       public (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int); }
>
> -keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {    public void *(android.view.View);    public void *(android.view.MenuItem); }
>
> -keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
>       static android.os.Parcelable$Creator CREATOR; }
>
> -keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
>       public static ; }

5  At this point my project builds, but fails due to some class cast exceptions around logging.  This takes me back to step 3, where I wish a reasonable proguard-project.txt had been generated based of the eclipse library dependencies.  Clearly the on I've created isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

After having updated the SDK, you must also make sure to update the project itself:

```
android update project --path MyAndroidProjectDirectory
```

In recent Android SDKs, this should create `proguard-project.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you got something wrong with your setup in general, creating new Android project, writes down proguard config file as well. So just set up dummy project and check its folder - it should be there. Copy it back to your current project and adjust if needed.